# Is it possible to typedef a parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Is it possible to typedef a parameter pack? For example

```
template<class T, class... Args>
struct A
{
    typedef T Type; // We typedef it, then its derived class can use it.
                    // How about for parameter packs?

    // Option 1:
    typedef Args Arguments;

    // Option 2:
    using Arguments = Args;

    // Option 3: I can put in a tuple, but how can I untuple it to a pack
    typedef tuple<Args...> Tuple;
};
```

I want to using the above technique to implement the following

```
template<int... VALUES>
struct IntegralSequence
{
    enum { SIZE = sizeof...(VALUES) };

    template <unsigned I>
    struct At
    {
        enum { VALUE = typename tuple_element<I, 
                       tuple<integral_constant<int, VALUES>...>>::type::value
             };
    };
};

template<unsigned N>
struct AscendingSequence
{
    typedef IntegralSequence<AscendingSequence<N-1>::VALUES..., N> Type;
    using VALUES = Type::VALUES; // if it works
};

template<>
struct AscendingSequence<1>
{
    typedef IntegralSequence<0> Type;
    using VALUES = Type::VALUES; // if it works
};
```

Comment: *"I can put in a tuple, but how can I untuple it to a pack"* With partial specialization, deduction or the indices trick.

Comment: You can use `Args... args;`

Comment: If you can coarsely describe the use case, i.e. where you want to unpack them, it might be easier to construct a working example. (@dyp gave three possibilities but they are each suited for a limited set of use cases)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can pack them in a `tuple`, or in a arbitrary empty class template (I prefer to call it `pack`):

```
template<typename... Args>
struct pack { };

template<class T, class... Args>
struct A
{
    using args = pack<Args...>;
};
```

If you are then given `A` e.g. in function template and you want to deduce `Args...`, you can do it like this:

```
template<typename... Args, typename A>
void f(pack<Args...>, A a) { /* use Args... here */ }

template<typename A>
void f(A a) { f(typename A::args(), a); }
```

`pack` being empty is convenient in situations like that. Otherwise you'd need some other means to pass `args` without actually passing a `tuple` that contains data (e.g. wrapping it into yet another empty struct).

Or, in a class template specialization:

```
template<typename T, typename = typename T::args>
struct B_impl;

template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct B_impl <T, pack<Args...> >
{
    // use Args... here
};

template<typename T>
using B = B_impl<T>;
```

I guess these are the options of deduction and partial specialization that @dyp mentioned.

---

**EDIT** This is in response to the edited question. Ok, this is clearly an XY problem. If `IntegralSequence` is all you need, you can use `std::make_integer_sequence` in C++14 or check [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22967492/2644390) just a few minutes ago for an efficient implementation.

Comment: +1 for using wrapper type other than tuple, it's all about separation of concerns.

Comment: Just want to implement make_integer_sequence by myself and pops out this question.

Comment: @user1899020 I don't believe it! This looks like an X-ABCDEF-Y problem :-)

Comment: As a bikeshed, I like calling `pack` `types`: describe its contents, not its source, sort of.  Plus types are not the only kind of parameter pack.

Comment: @iavr I edit it. Please see my implementation scheme.

Comment: @Yakk True. Unfortunately, in my projects, I have a *namespace* called `types` where all metaprogramming takes place :-)